# How to run a Jupyter Notebook with space in relative path from another notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I'm working in a Jupyter notebook and need to run another Jupyter notebook. This is normally straightforward using `%run` but the path to the other notebook is relative and contains spaces.

This gives the following error:

```py
%run '..//..//2. Data Collection//Data Cleaning//Account Data Clean-up.ipynb'
ERROR:root:File `"'..//..//2..py"` not found.
```

Clearly the notebook is encountering the space after the "2." and attempts to add a "py" to run the file. I've tried to add and "r" before the string but that didn't work. FYI I'm working in Jupyter Lab on a Windows machine in Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

Try with escaping the spaces. like this:

`'..//..//2.\ Data\ Collection//Data\ Cleaning//Account\ Data\ Clean-up.ipynb'`

it should work

Comment: Worked for me, at least for using %run to load python instead of another notebook.